# ScriptableObjects events execution order?

Tags: unity, c#, scriptable-object

Given the code:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "newGameManagerInstance", menuName = "Game/Game Manager Instance")]
public class GameManagerSO : ScriptableObject
{
    private GameManager instance;

    public GameManager Instance { get { return instance; } set { instance = value; } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("2");
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Debug.Log("3");
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Debug.Log("4");
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. **Why the output in console when I enter play mode is "3" and then "2"?** Shouldn't `OnDisable` be executed after `OnEnable`?
2. I'm using this scriptable object to hold an object reference only (I don't have the need to serialize the object, it's just a handy way I found to pass that reference through scenes without committing to singletons); **can I code all initialization code for the object in `OnEnable` method?** Can I assume it will always execute before any `MonoBehaviour` read it?

Also

Comment: @D.Kallan The reference text you quoted is for `MonoBehaviour`. My question is about `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: Completely right, sorry. I deleted my comments to not bother others, The documentation on ScriptableObjects feels almost the same yet also feels like a C+P (I'm talking about that line indicating a OnDisable is called followed by OnEnable). https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.OnDisable.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `ScriptableObject`'s `Awake` and `OnEnable` methods are called (in that order) as soon as the object is loaded.

This occurs when...

- Loading a scene that contains a reference to the object (including in the editor)
- Reloading recently referenced `ScriptableObjects` after a code change
- Clicking on the object in the Project window or reference selector widget

That means if you're testing a scene that contains a reference to this `ScriptableObject`, it's *already enabled* before you click the Play Mode button.

To match the event flow you observe in a built game, Unity starts-up the object from scratch when entering Play Mode. (Imagine you were using your `OnEnable` method to generate a random seed for a roguelike's procedural dungeon generation - if it didn't do this, you'd always get the same dungeon when testing in the editor)

But since the object was already started-up, in order to re-start it we have to shut it down first. That means calling `OnDisable` on it.

So the order of events you see when entering play mode is `OnDisable` -> `OnEnable`, but only because we've narrowed our view too far. If we step back and look at the wider timeline we'll see something like this:

1. Launch Unity editor and open a scene referencing the object, or select the object in the inspector

   `Awake` -> `OnEnable`
2. Enter Play Mode

   -> `OnDisable` -> `OnEnable`
3. Load a different scene that does not reference this object

   -> `OnDisable`

So it is true that `OnDisable` occurs after `OnEnable`. Specifically, the `OnDisable` in (2) occurs after the `OnEnable` in (1), just like the `OnDisable` in (3) follows the `OnEnable` in (2).

> Can I code all initialization code for the object in the `OnEnable` method? Can I assume it will always execute before any `MonoBehaviour` can read it?

Yes. That is exactly the purpose of these methods.